# How to check if part of a class is part of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that is populated by a random line from a previously determined list. The list is populated by a CSV file. The class looks like this:

```
class Gem:
    def __init__ (self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = float(value)
```

The lists populate correctly and Item is populated correctly using the class. I have 6 lists and I need to check if item.name is part of any of them. I thought:

```
if item.name in COMMONGEMS:
    item.value = random.range(4, 17)
```

I do this for each list, but whilst I don't get any errors, this doesn't ever get a match when it should.

How should I accomplish this instead?

Edit: In response to interjey, The list would look like this once loaded from the CSV:

```
print (COMMONGEMS)
[['Banded', '0'], ['Eye Agate', '0'], ['Moss Agate', '0'], ['Azurite', '0'], ['Blue quartz', '0'], ['Hematite', '0'], ['Lapis Lazuli', '0'], ['Malachite', '0'], ['Obsidian', '0'], ['Rhodochrosite', '0'], ['Tiger Eye', '0'], ['Turquoise', '0'], ['Freshwater', '0'], ['Irregular Pearl', '0']]
```

Comment: Is it a list of names or a list of `Gem` instances? Can you show an example?

Comment: @interjay I have editied the question with a response to you. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is not checking the name within the list of lists. It is only checking the  inner list itself which would not match your query.
A simple loop can look into the inner list at the names:

```
for element in COMMONGEMS:
    if item.name == element[0]:
        item.value = random.range(4, 17)
```

I used `==` instead of `in` because there is probably a gem which has a name `in` another name, but is not that name. Such as `ruby` matching `star ruby` etc.

Comment: `is` checks identity, not equality. Use `==`.

Comment: It's better to use any I think ```if any(item.name == e[0] for e in COMMONGEMS):```

Comment: I debated using `any`, but he might need the element itself for the value so I left it as is. `any` is awesome though.

Comment: maybe ```next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda e: item.name != e[0], COMMONGEMS), None)```

Comment: Using == seems to work a treat, or at least I am getting further than before. I am getting another error: item.value = random.range(2, 9)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'range'    which is lies and I don't know why it's coming back with this .I believe this is unrelated so I'll open another question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: make sure you `import random` at the beginning of your file, its also `randrange`, so [`random.randrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) <- link

Answer (score 2):

If item.name is a string like "Banded", item.name won't be found in COMMONGEMS.

`['Banded', '0'] in COMMONGEMS => true`

`'Banded' in COMMONGEMS => false`

**Edit:**
Instead of a list you can use a dictionary:

```
COMMONGEMS = {'Banded': '0' , 'Azurite' : '0'}

if item.name in COMMONGEMS:
    item.value = random.range(4, 17)
```

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: +1 for dictionaries, you could go further and use `csv.DictReader` too.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I may add a description to the gems class at some point and I don't think a dictionary would work for that. Thanks though, I will bear this in mind for the future.